# How to pass void return type into Json

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Please help me. How can I pass message from void to return type?

**WebApi.cs**

```
public void DeleteById(int id)
{
    string meassga = "";
    try
    {
        objser.DeleteBYId(id);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        meassga = "" + ex;
    }

}
```

**Mvc.cs**

```
public JsonResult DeleteById(int id)
{
   string meassga = "";
   ss.DeleteBYId(id);
   return Json ( meassga,  JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet );
}
```

Here I'm passing data from mvc to webApi & I want to show error details from api controller to mvc json control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.  You have a couple of options, change your webapi method to return a string, or throw the exception like this:

```
public void DeleteById(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            objser.DeleteBYId(id);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception($"Exception in DeleteById({id}) - {ex.Message}", ex);
        }
    }
```

then in the controller:

```
public JsonResult DeleteById(int id)
    {
        try 
        {
           ss.DeleteBYId(id);
           return Json ("Deleted successfully", JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
          return Json ( ex.Message,  JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet );
        }
    }
```

... similar.  Without throwing exceptions another common strategy is to create a return class like this:

```
public class ApiResult<T>
{
   public string Message { get; set; }
   public T Result { get; set; }
   public bool Success { get; set; }
}
```

And implement that as the thing all your api calls return.